# How to rename roles in Sonata Admin

Tags: sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

Hello Sonata/Symfony developers,
how can I rename the roles in SonataUser, instead of ROLE_ADMIN I want to have Adminstrator, instead of ROLE_CLIENT - to have Client etc..

Thanks!

[image]